# draw lines symmetrically spaced out (swift4)

Tags: ios, line, swift4, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw lines to be space out just like loose leaf paper. I am trying to find a sequence on how to space the lines. The code I have below is a example of hat I am looking for. The problem is If I follow the sequence of adding 1/8 to the next line and the lines continue to get closer together. [image]

```
    import UIKit

class draw: UIView {

var line = UIBezierPath()
var line3 = UIBezierPath()
var lin2 = UIBezierPath()
var line1 = UIBezierPath()
func grapher() {
   line.move(to: .init(x:0, y: bounds.height/1.5))
    line.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height / 1.5))
    UIColor.brown.setStroke()
    line.lineWidth = 2
    line.stroke()


    line3.move(to: .init(x:0, y: bounds.height / 1.375))
    line3.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height / 1.375))
    UIColor.red.setStroke()
    line3.lineWidth = 2
    line3.stroke()

    line3.move(to: .init(x:0, y: bounds.height / 1.25 ))
    line3.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height / 1.25))
    UIColor.red.setStroke()
    line3.lineWidth = 2
    line3.stroke()

    line3.move(to: .init(x:0, y: bounds.height / 1.125 ))
    line3.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height / 1.125))
    UIColor.red.setStroke()
    line3.lineWidth = 2
    line3.stroke()

 }
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    grapher()
}
}
```

Comment: If you divide by a number *x/8* that is the same as multiplying by *8/x*. The fractions in your case are *8/12*, *8/11*, *8/10* and *8/9*. The differences between those are not equal. From your question I think you wanted to *divide* by *8* and *multiply* by *1* through *7*, so fractions *1/8*, ..., *7/8*?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would have used addition rather than division:

```
let step = bounds.height / 8 // or however big you want the gap to be
var yForLine = step

// draw your first line line using yForLine

yForLine += step

// draw next line using yForLine

// etc.
```